# How does JavaScript compare object passed in method as arguments?

Tags: javascript

I saw interview question  [here](https://performancejs.com/post/hde6d32/The-Best-Frontend-JavaScript-Interview-Questions-(Written-by-a-Frontend-Engineer) in debugging section (first question).

```js
function greet(person) {
  if (person == { name: 'amy' }) {
    return 'hey amy'
  } else {
    return 'hey arnold'
  }
}
greet({ name: 'amy' })
```

This is printing `hey arnold`.

I want to understand why this is happening?
Any explanation or direction to resource would be much appreciated.

Comment: == will just do referential comparison. As these 2 are different objects, it won't be true. If you want to learn how to do deep comparison of objects refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: Thank You @MahendraPratap for the link. I've better understanding now.

Answer (score 1):

objects are checked for equality by reference, not value.

```
{a: 1} === {a: 1} // returns false
```

Comment: Thank you @david-ko for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are compared by *reference*, not by *value*. Two objects with the same properties and values are still different objects.

Comment: I see. Completely forgot about check by reference. Thank You @eric-lippert.